# autofill combobox based on another combo box selection using HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, combobox

Please auto fill combo box based on another combo box selection using HTML

E.g. *if first combo box selection value equals "a" then 
          second combo box value equals (a,b,c,d)
       else if first combo box selection value equals "b" then
            combo box value equals (e,f,g,h)
             ......

any help is highly welcome

Comment: Simplest way would be to use ajax request and populate second list with result returned by ajax background request. This request would have to be triggered by first list change (option selection).

Comment: @StormoPL i need a code sample

Comment: Here you have step by step how to use ajax to load data into list: http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/. Just put ajax call inside $('combo-selector').change(function(e) {your-ajax})

Comment: @StormoPL i have check the link, is not what i really want, i want something look like this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972669/how-to-automatically-change-values-of-combobox-value-based-on-input-value-in-tex` in this page

Comment: So you have the solution - assuming that you have some small constant list of values. If the list is stored in database you will have to fetch and load to combo based on request limiting options only to those you need (and this is what ajax is for).

Comment: @StormoPL am not using database so i don't want to load from database i just want to populate the second combo box with the list of local government base on the state you selected in first combo box